# Converting a class function to iterate through multiple images with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV to detect images in real-time. This is working with single images. I'm trying to update the script to work with multiple images at once with the end goal to be to detect a few different elements on the screen at once and draw rectangles around them while returning the centre points of the images for use elsewhere.

I've gotten as far as passing the images in from my `main.py` file and initiating the search.

```
# load source images
source_images = glob.glob(r'C:\\\\\\\*.jpg')

# perform the search
search = Search(source_images)
```

I can't seem to pass `loaded_images` into my `find` function. I've tried defining `loaded_images` in the Class properties and within the constructor but neither work and give me the error `NameError: name 'loaded_images' is not defined`

```
class Search:

    # properties
    needle_img = None
    needle_w = 0
    needle_h = 0
    method = None

    # empty list to store the source images
    #loaded_images = [] <-------------------------------------------------

    # constructor                                        
    def __init__(self, source_images, method=cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):
                     
        # Set the method we're using when we load the image 
        self.method = method

        # empty list to store the source images
        # loaded_images = [] <-------------------------------------------------
        
        # load the needle image into loaded_iamges array
        for img in source_images:
            self.needle_img = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            loaded_images.append(self.needle_img)

            return self.loaded_images <--------------------------------

    def find(self, haystack_img, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None):
        
        for img in loaded_images:
            # Save the dimensions of the needle images
            self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
            self.needle_h = self.needle_img.shape[0]
            
            # run the OpenCV algorithm
            result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, self.needle_img, self.method)
```

I also wrote this next code segment that matches multiple images on a screenshot rather than a real-time image to try and figure out what I was doing wrong. It's helped me get this far but I am now stuck.

```
# load source images
source_images = glob.glob(r'C:\\\\\\\*.jpg')
# empty list to store the source images
loaded_images = []

for img in source_images:
    needle_img = cv.imread(img, 0)
    loaded_images.append(needle_img)

haystack_img = cv.imread(r'C:\\\\\\both.jpg')
haystack_img = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#loop for matching
for needles in loaded_images:
    
    #save the dimensions of the needle images
    (tH, tW) = needles.shape[:2]
    result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needles, cv.TM_CCOEFF)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
    top_left = max_loc
    
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + tW, top_left[1] + tH)
    cv.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)

cv.imshow('Result', haystack_img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pass loaded images directly to find:

```
class Search:              
    def __init__(self, source_images, method=cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):
                     
        # Set the method we're using when we load the image 
        self.method = method

    def find(self, haystack_img, loaded_images, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None):
        for img in loaded_images:
            # Save the dimensions of the needle images
            self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
            self.needle_h = self.needle_img.shape[0]
            # you are overwriting the same needle_w and needle_h variable over and over again in a loop...
            
            # run the OpenCV algorithm
            result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, self.needle_img, self.method)
```

Or store loaded images in field:

```
class Search:                                    
    def __init__(self, source_images, method=cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):
        # Set the method we're using when we load the image 
        self.method = method

        self.loaded_images = [] 
        # load the needle image into loaded_iamges array
        for img in source_images:
            needle_img = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
            self.loaded_images.append(needle_img)

    def find(self, haystack_img, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None):
        for img in self.loaded_images:
            # Save the dimensions of the needle images
            self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
            self.needle_h = self.needle_img.shape[0]
            # you are overwriting the same needle_w and needle_h variable over and over again in a loop...
            
            # run the OpenCV algorithm
            result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, self.needle_img, self.method)
```

In general you need to learn about scopes and difference between class and instance variables. Also I don't see here why you would need class when you would probably only have one instance of it, so maybe read about OOP in general.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @konserw digesting this now. Honestly, I was following a tutorial and he used classes. I've a class that does the searching and a class that captures the application window in real time. I'm not sure if there is a more sensible approach!

Comment: Maybe find tutorial about OOP in python first before following tutorial on openCV that probably assumes you know how classes, instances of objects, scopes, etc. works

Comment: Probably right, there are an awful lot of black holes and it's taking a lot of trial and error to piece things together. I've been told elsewhere that getting stuck into a project like this is a much better (if bumpier) way to learn. It's more fun at least!

Comment: getting the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' at line `self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]` if I print both `needle_img` and `self.loaded_images` directly above find both return correctly. If I print(self.needle_img) inside `find` it returns none. This was using method two you've posted above. This means we're not passing the variable right if it's empty?

Comment: Checked with imshow and it's returning the images correctly in `needle_imge` under __init__ it's just not passing to find

Comment: updated: Tried both methods and I'm getting the same error; `  self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`. When I `print(loaded_images) both in __init__ and in find I get the same array returning. Which is expected right and I'm onto a new issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in this case. Either define `load_images` as an instance variable with  `self.`. But then you should call it as `self.loaded_images` everywhere within the class.

```
class Search:

self.loaded_images = []

for ...
self.loaded_images.append(...)
```

Or, you can define as a parameter in the function.

```
def find(self, loaded_images, haystack_img, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None):
```

Then you can leave the definition of `load_images` as it is currently in `__init__` method (uncomment `load_images=[ ]`), but be sure that you call the `find` function with your `load_images` where you had "loaded" images.

It is completely up to you how to structure your variable.

Comment: Thanks @prefect I think that makes sense. Is there best practice in this space at all?

Comment: As @konserw mentioned, you can follow a basic OOP tutorial. Or you might just choose one approach for now and go with it. I am sure everything will make more sense on the way while you are learning from your goals and mistakes :)

Comment: Appreciate that. Will try both approaches and get back if needed! Otherwise will upvote shortly.

Comment: Tried both methods and I'm getting the same error; `  self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`. When I `print(loaded_images) both in __init__ and in find I get the same array returning. Which is expected right and I'm onto a new issue?