# Why is my image that was correctly loading in one function only loading as 1 x 4 pixels in a different function?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm storing two images in `loaded_needle_images = []` and I'm checking they're loading correctly with `cv.imshow('needle_img', self.needle_img)`

```
def __init__(self, source_needle_images, method=cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):       

loaded_needle_images= []
for img in source_needle_images:
    self.needle_img = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    loaded_needle_images.append(self.needle_img)

    cv.imshow('needle_img', self.needle_img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

When then when I pass them into a different function are they loading as 1 x 4 pixels shown below?

```
 def find(self, haystack_img, loaded_needle_images, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None):
              
        processed_images = np.asarray(loaded_needle_images)

        cv.imshow('processed image', processed_images)
        cv.waitKey(0)
        cv.imshow('loaded image', loaded_needle_images)
        cv.waitKey(0)
```

Both `imshow` commands bring up the same image meaning it's been converted by `asarray` but I'm not sure how/why I'm going from an actual image to the four pixels shown below.

Update: To show where I'm calling `find`

```
# the window to capture 
wincap = WindowCapture('x')

# load needle images and start the matching process 
source_needle_images = glob.glob(r'C:\\\\\\\*.jpg')
search = Search(source_needle_images)

loop_time = time()
while(True):

    # get an updated image of the game
    haystack_img = wincap.get_screenshot()

    # display the processed image
    points = search.find(haystack_img, 0.85, 'rectangles')
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you calling `find`? Are you sure you are passing it the correct "loaded_needle_images"? It doesn't seem like you are storing that anywhere in the `__init__`.

Comment: Updated. Find is being called from my main.py whereas this sits within a class of it's own. I've two classes, one handles capturing an application window in real-time (window capture), and another (search) the handles the matchtemplate work. I have it working with one image and I'm trying update the search class to work with multiple source images rather than just one.

Comment: The second argument for `find` should be `loaded_needle_images`, but you provide it with `0.85` when you call `find`. Where do you expect the find function to be getting `loaded_needle_images`? Please clarify.

Comment: I'd asked that exact question elsewhere and got this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66629115/ I thought it was being passed from __init__

Comment: You can't pass from init without telling it to pass from init. Based on the code you provided, `loaded_needle_images` in `__init__` disappears from the ether as soon as `__init__` is done processing. I'll provide a more detailed answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes in Python don't have anyway to "automatically" pass values between functions. If you are creating data in an `__init__` function, the only way you can get access to it again is to save it in the instance (ie, self). You can not return values from an `__init__` function.

Updated `__init__`:

```py
def __init__(self, source_needle_images, method=cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):       

self.loaded_needle_images= [] # create list in the instance
for img in source_needle_images:
    self.needle_img = cv.imread(img, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    self.loaded_needle_images.append(self.needle_img) # update the list created in the instance

    cv.imshow('needle_img', self.needle_img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

Updated `def find(...)`:

```py
 def find(self, haystack_img, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None): # don't need to pass in "loaded_needle_images"
         if len(self.loaded_needle_images) < 1:
             raise AttributeError("Object not properly initialized, no loaded_needle_images") # adding for extra error processing to catch if loaded_needle_images is empty before attempting to run.     
        processed_images = np.asarray(self.loaded_needle_images) # grab loaded_needle_images from instance

        cv.imshow('processed image', processed_images)
        cv.waitKey(0)
        cv.imshow('loaded image', self.loaded_needle_images) # grab loaded_needle_images from instance
        cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Works and thanks for the comment explanations